# Read file line by line and store in a list

Tags: list, file-io, ocaml

I have a input.txt file with few lines of text. I am trying to store those lines in a list l. I think I am doing correct but list l is not getting updated. please help.

```
let l = []
let () = 
  let ic = open_in "input.txt" 
  in
  try
    while true do
      let line = input_line ic 
      in
      let rec append(a, b) = match a with
      |[] -> [b]
      |c::cs -> c::append(cs,b)
      in
      append(l, line)
      (* print_endline line *)
    done
  with End_of_file ->
close_in ic;;
```

Apart from Warning 10, I am not getting any error.

Comment: http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/basics.html

Comment: @Thomas At least give me a clue. I hv been devoted more than 30min to it.

Comment: `append(l, line)` does NOT modify the original list `l` but create a new list from `l` and `line`.  `l` is unchanged.  Your code discards the new list therefore nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let l = []
```

Variables in OCaml are immutable, so no matter what code you write after this line, `l` will always be equal to `[]`.

Comment: but this changes l:                                                               let l = [["hi";"there"]];;
let rec append(a, b) = match a with
|[] -> [b]
|c::cs -> c::append(cs,b)
in
append(l,["hello"; "world"]);;

Comment: I don't understand why in one case list is being updated but in other it is not.

Comment: No the code in your comment does NOT change `l`.  `append` creates a new list from `l` but `l` is unchanged.  Try `l;;` to see it keeps the original value.

Comment: U r right but the question remains how do I store lines of file in a list.

Comment: You can create a reference ;-) (let l = ref [] and then you write l := line :: !l)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are caught in imperative programming - a good thing to start with OCaml!

Typical functional and recursive programming would read a file like this:

Read a line, then append "read a line" to it. At End_of_File you finish the list with [].